# Regex Negative look ahead in ADFS claim rule

Tags: regex, adfs, adfs4.0

I need to grant a claim to everyone not matching a particular LDAP attribute.  I want to use a regex with a negative look ahead to perform this "not" clause

```
c1:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", Value =~ "^(?!Test User).*$"]
 => issue(Type = "http://goofyclaim", Value = "youre not a tester");
```

the above rule doesn't seem to get satisfied by my test users.   Something wrong with  the regex? or does ADFS4.0 not support it.  I don't see any errors in the ADFS event logs.

this is a win2016srv on a win2012r2 AD domain.

for reference, this rule does work:

```
c1:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", Value =~ "(?i)^Test User1"]  
 => issue(Type = "http://somethignelseentreily", Value = "imispellwhendriving");
```

Comment: Have you tested in the regex tester? https://regex101.com/

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT I did, but I had to play with the ADFS usage of the expression a little (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(leaving my other answer so other can see its not the `right` answer)

```
NOT EXISTS([Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", Value =~ "^Test User"])
 => issue(Type = "http://somethignelseentreily", Value = "all");
```

Comment: so Im talking too myself - sue me

Answer (score 0):

first I need to use (found here [ADFS rules language terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/solution-guides/claims-transformation-rules-language#BKMK_LT)) for REGEXP_NOT_MATCH

```
!~
```

Next, I had to restructure the regex mode modifier a little, by having the case insensitivity inside the ^ idenifier

```
c1:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", Value !~ "^(?i)Test User"]
 => issue(Type = "http://somethignelseentreily", Value = "imispellwhendriving");
```

Comment: I'm removing this as the answer, as I'm experiencing weird results.